# How to query a list of partitionKeys with Dynamo DB Enhanced Client in AWS SDK v2

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have a table with both partitionKey and sortKey are defined.

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/ddb-en-client-use-multirecord-query.html, I can query single partitionKey with `QueryConditional.keyEqualTo`:

```
QueryConditional keyEqual = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(b -> b.partitionValue("movie01"));
PageIterable<MovieActor> pagedResults = movieActorTable.query(keyEqual)
```

But how can I query all records whose partitionKey are in ["movie01", "movie02", "movie04"]?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not provide support for `BatchQuery`. There is a workaround where you can use the PartiQL API which is a SQL wrapper for DynamoDB where you can provide up to 50 partitions keys. For that you'll have to use the low level client.

```
aws dynamodb execute-statement \ 
--statement 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK IN [1,2,3,4]'
```

Using the enhanced client you will need to spin or parallel queries from the client side.